# Determining the Class Inside a TD Tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Using python beautifulsoup I am trying to find all of the `<tr>` tags of an HTML page. However I would like to filter out any `<tr>` tag that has a certain class inside one of the `<td>` tags.

I have tried to filter rows out that have the class "Warning" within the `<td>` tag with the below code.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('tr', class_=lambda c: 'Warning' not in c))
```

I know it is not filtering out the "warning class" because I am using `<tr>` inside the `find_all` function but if I try to use `td` it gives me a `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''
<tr role="row" class="odd red" data-id="32">
   <td role="gridcell" class="Warning">33</td>
   <td role="gridcell">Ralph</td>
   <td role="gridcell">List 2</td>
   <td role="gridcell">FE</td>
   <td role="gridcell">07/12/1996</td>
</tr>
<tr role="row" class="even red" data-id="33">
   <td role="gridcell">34</td>
   <td role="gridcell">Mary</td>
   <td role="gridcell">List 2</td>
   <td role="gridcell">SOTLTM</td>
   <td role="gridcell">08/12/1996</td>
</tr>
<tr role="row" class="odd red" data-id="34">
   <td role="gridcell">35</td>
   <td role="gridcell">Tom</td>
   <td role="gridcell">List 2</td>
   <td role="gridcell">SOTLTM</td>
   <td role="gridcell">09/12/1996</td>
</tr>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('td', class_=lambda c: 'Warning' not in c))
```

Answer (score 0):

`class=` is not an attribute on most of your `<td>` elements. This causes `c` to be set to `None` in your lambda, so you can automatically let those through the filter with a conditional test:

```
print(soup.find_all('td', class_=lambda c: not c or 'Warning' not in c))
#                                          ^^^^^^^^
```

#### Output

```
[<td role="gridcell">Ralph</td>, 
 <td role="gridcell">List 2</td>, 
 <td role="gridcell">FE</td>, 
 <td role="gridcell">07/12/1996</td>, 
 <td role="gridcell">34</td>, 
 <td role="gridcell">Mary</td>, 
 <td role="gridcell">List 2</td>, 
 <td role="gridcell">SOTLTM</td>, 
 <td role="gridcell">08/12/1996</td>, 
 <td role="gridcell">35</td>, 
 <td role="gridcell">Tom</td>, 
 <td role="gridcell">List 2</td>, 
 <td role="gridcell">SOTLTM</td>, 
 <td role="gridcell">09/12/1996</td>]
```

---

Moving from there, we can apply this conditional on your primary concern, which is filter the `<tr>` elements according to their children:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    if not bool(tr.find_all('td', class_=lambda c: c and 'Warning' in c)):
        print(tr) # or print(tr.find_all('td')) if you'd like to 
                  # access only the children of the filtered <tr>s
```

#### Output

```
<tr class="even red" data-id="33" role="row">
<td role="gridcell">34</td>
<td role="gridcell">Mary</td>
<td role="gridcell">List 2</td>
<td role="gridcell">SOTLTM</td>
<td role="gridcell">08/12/1996</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd red" data-id="34" role="row">
<td role="gridcell">35</td>
<td role="gridcell">Tom</td>
<td role="gridcell">List 2</td>
<td role="gridcell">SOTLTM</td>
<td role="gridcell">09/12/1996</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks ggorlen.  In the end I would like it to filter out the complete <tr> if it finds "Warning" in any of the <td>'s .  In other words in the end I would like it to be more like.

<td role="gridcell">Mary</td>, 

<td role="gridcell">List 2</td>, 

<td role="gridcell">SOTLTM</td>, 

<td role="gridcell">08/12/1996</td>, 

<td role="gridcell">35</td>, 

<td role="gridcell">Tom</td>, 

<td role="gridcell">List 2</td>, 

<td role="gridcell">SOTLTM</td>, 

<td role="gridcell">09/12/1996</td>]

Comment: Take a look at my update and let me know if it doesn't work out for you.